# I want a proxy in Apigee to call itself every 1 minute

Tags: apigee

I have a proxy in apigee.I want that proxy to call itself every 1 minute.
Can anyone help me with simple policy/javascript policy so that it calls itself every 1 minute?

Why does google has no auto call function?

Comment: Can you run your proxy with batch? And then setting the batch schedule to run every 1 minute.

Comment: @PIm H.Yes.Can you explain to me how it can be done?Is it possible in Apigee?Please explain?

Comment: I'm really sorry, I'm still beginner of Apigee. What I have suggested to you is from others in my work space but I haven't done it by myself so that is a reason why I can't explain to you. Maybe you have wait for others answer or try to visit Apiee Community, maybe someone can answer your question cleary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a good practice to call API Proxy continuously from same proxy or from different proxy in Apigee. Doing so you may bring down Server if you are dealing with large data.

However, you can do outside of Apigee by running Jenkins job which calls your proxy every minute or creating a unix or batch script and run it as a corn job.

Shell script: On unix create a test.sh file and add curl  command and any other instructions you want. Follow below article for more details on curl.

https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/04/curl-examples/?utm_source=feedburner

Now, Schedule it using corn job. below post describes how to do it.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/852070/automatically-run-a-command-every-5-minutes/852074

Thanks

Comment: This procedure is tested?

Comment: Thanks Got it.Is there any other scheduler like node schedule?Can anyone guide me how to do the same in node schedule?Is it linux based?

Comment: please I dont have option to have a external  linux server?What is the option then?

Comment: It doesn’t have to be linux, you can also do it on Windows or in any programming language.